How to measure performance metric in a dynamic programming algorithm
I am trying to use the Cell Updates Per Second (CUPS) metric to measure the performance of the sequence alignment algorithm. I saw the metric being used in several papers (ref1, ref2)but none of them have explained how it is really being computed.
It is essentially processing the cells in a 2D matrix.
What I tried is as follows:
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
alignment_score = alignment(seq1, seq2, seq1_len, seq2_len);
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);

double elapsed_time =  (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +(double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec);
printf ("elapsed time = %f seconds\n",elapsed_time);
double gcups = ((seq1_len * seq2_len )/1000000000.0) / (elapsed_time) ;
printf("GCUPS: %10f \n", gcups);

But I am not sure if this the right definition. Could you please confirm or point me to a reference on how it is measured?

Re “I saw the metric being used in several papers…”: Cite the papers.

@EricPostpischil I added two of them

Any comments would be appreciated...

You used gettimeofday for time ellapse measurment. I propose using clock_gettime.
clock_gettime (with the CLOCK_MONOTONIC flag) is guaranteed to be monotonic. This means the time returned will always be increasing relative to the program's start, even if the system clock is adjusted. This is crucial for benchmarking as it ensures the measured time reflects the actual execution time. But gettimeofday is not monotonic. The system clock can be adjusted manually or due to NTP synchronization or leap seconds, causing jumps in the returned value and affecting benchmark accuracy.
In addition, clock_gettime can potentially offer higher resolution (nanoseconds) compared to gettimeofday (microseconds) on some systems. This allows for more precise measurement of short execution times.
I used glibc info and this page as reference.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define UNUSED(v) ((void) v)
#define BILLION   1000000000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  UNUSED(argc);
  UNUSED(argv);

  struct timespec start, end;

  /* first argument is of type clockid_t. possible values:
   *   - CLOCK_MONOTONIC
   *   - CLOCK_REALTIME
   *   - CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW (Supported by glibc, as far as I know)
   *   - ... Refer to your libc reference manual for other possible values
   */
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

  /* Do your hard work here */

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

  int64_t nanoseconds = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * BILLION;
  nanoseconds += (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
  double seconds = (double) nanoseconds / (double) BILLION;
  printf("the hard work took %f seconds\n", seconds);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

